# How to write firefox addon to change the searchbar on right side to my own search service

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, add-on, search-box

Basically I have created one simple search engine in php.

I want to create a firefox addon, after installing that it will automatically add my search engine URL to the search box. And this should be default one as now "Google" is the default. So when user type anything, the suggestions should be coming from my webservice.

I'm using FF 21

Any working code or documentation will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

- Simplest method to create a search plugin is to use it as OpenSearch plugin.

  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Creating_OpenSearch_plugins_for_Firefox

  And OpenSearch plugin supports 'search suggestions' using json. But, It'll not be a default one without manually changing it.
- Next method is to create a extension using XUL & JS to do whatever you want.

  https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension

  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31736/Introduction-to-Building-FireFox-Add-ons-Extension

  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Firefox_addons_developer_guide/Let%27s_build_a_Firefox_extension